# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF. It happend when I try to do "Auth" staff

Tags: php, authentication, fuelphp

I can't open my "member" page. I get error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF.
I'm trying to do "Auth check" but I get error like above. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Additionally, this file is in APPATH/classes/controller/member.php

```
<?php

class Controller_Member extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'member/template';
    public $is_admin = false;

    public function before(){
        parent::before
        // below is the reason I got error for
        if (!Auth::check() and Request::active()->action != 'login') {
            Response::redirect('member/login');
        }

        if (Auth::member(100)){
            $this->is_admin = true;
        }

        View::set_global('is_admin', $this->is_admin);
    }

    public function action_login(){
        Auth::check() and Response::redirect('member');

        if (Input::post('username') and Input::post('password')){
            $username = Input::post('username');
            $password = Input::post('password');
            $auth = Auth::instance(); 
        }
    }

    //ログインフォームの表示
    $this->template->title = 'ギアらはここ';
    $this->template->content = View::forge('member/form');

}

public function action_logout(){
    //ログアウト
    $auth = Auth::instance();
    $auth->logout();
    //'member'にリダイレクト
    Response::redirect('member');
}

}
```

Comment: `parent::before` ?? missing semi-colon

Comment: **Use some sensible CODE INDENTATION** And the problems (many) become quite obvious. _Clue, which `}` ends your class definition????_

Comment: Sorry, but syntax error is not the category that needs a fuelphp flag, and also I don't believe that this question belongs here. The error message is quite clear, the related questions section is full of duplicates, and you are asking us to find the error instead of you. So I downvoted your question. No offense, it just doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `();` in your `parent::before`-call. That error you're getting are kind of confusing to beginners. It actually means:

*"There's something wrong **before** this piece of code, because I didn't expect to meet the word `Auth` here."*

So basically, when you get a Syntax-error, start by inspecting the code right before the place where you're getting your error.

You do, however, also have multiple errors further down.

```
<?php

class Controller_Member extends Controller_Template
{

    public $template = 'member/template';
    public $is_admin = false;

    public function before()
    {
        parent::before();
        //            ^^^ Here, you missed the call ( () ) and semicolon ( ; ) 
        // ...
    }

    public function action_login()
    {
          Auth::check() and Response::redirect('member');
       // ^^ This line does not make sense without an if statement ^^
       // Except if it throws exceptions. 
    }

    //...

}
```

This part is not inside any methods, but directly in the class, and thereby does not make sense either (You must put it inside a function) :

```
    //ログインフォームの表示
$this->template->title = 'ギアらはここ';
$this->template->content = View::forge('member/form');
```

And right after that, you have another closing bracket `}`, which will also yield a syntax error. It's unclear where you meant those two lines; in my mind, they don't belong in either of your methods, but it seems like you just need to remove the closing bracket right before the two lines above.

All in all, be sure to indent your code properly, then you'll catch most of these errors.